# And so on and so forth - do I have to say the last part?

Tags: expressions

Will it sound weird/sloppy if I just say "...and so on.", instead of "...and so on and so forth."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all - “… and so on” and “… and so forth” are both quite commonly used individually. In some cases, using both together may be viewed as over-elaborate and/or melodramatic.